# Python Pandas - Dropping multiple columns through list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I tried searching for the answer to this question but was not able to find it... so here it goes.

I have a dataset with 23987 columns. I actually only want the information in 35 of those columns (quite spread out between them). I have put these 35 items in a list. I wanted to know if there is a quick way to **drop all the columns except those by passing the list**

I tried this:

```
df1.drop(df1.columns.difference([ALTJ_genes]), axis=1, inplace=True)
```

ALTJ_genes is the list with the 35 items. The error I get is:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do it, I know I can reach my goal by passing the individual columns but I want to know if with the list is possible. This would make the code much clearer.

In any case, thanks!

EDIT: I provide some screenshot, maybe it is useful.

[image: The first screenshot shows the head of the dataframe]
[image: The second screenshot shows how I can select one column]

Now, this is the complete error I get when passing the list with all the genes.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 df1[ALTJ_genes]

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in **getitem**(self, key)
   2984             if is_iterator(key):
   2985                 key = list(key)
-> 2986             indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)
   2987 
   2988         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter, raise_missing)
   1283                 # When setting, missing keys are not allowed, even with .loc:
   1284                 kwargs = {"raise_missing": True if is_setter else raise_missing}
-> 1285                 return self._get_listlike_indexer(obj, axis, **kwargs)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD9CL.png)
   1286         else:
   1287             try:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing)
   1090 
   1091         self._validate_read_indexer(
-> 1092             keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing
   1093         )
   1094         return keyarr, indexer

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
   1175                 raise KeyError(
   1176                     "None of [{key}] are in the [{axis}]".format(
-> 1177                         key=key, axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)
   1178                     )
   1179                 )

KeyError: "None of [Index([ ('APEX1',),  ('ASF1A',), ('CDKN2D',),   ('CIB1',),   ('DNA2',),\n       ('FAAP24',),  ('FANCM',),   ('GEN1',),   ('HRAS',),   ('LIG1',),\n         ('LIG3',),   ('MEN1',),  ('MRE11',),   ('MSH3',),   ('MSH6',),\n        ('NUDT1',),   ('MTOR',),  ('NABP2',),  ('NTHL1',),  ('PALB2',),\n        ('PARP1',),  ('PARP3',),  ('POLA1',),   ('POLM',),   ('POLQ',),\n       ('PRPF19',), ('RAD51D',),  ('RBBP8',),   ('RRM2',), ('RUVBL2',),\n         ('SOD1',),   ('KAT5',),    ('UNG',),    ('WRN',),  ('XRCC1',)],\n      dtype='object', name='Gene_Name')] are in the [columns]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need remove `[]` because `ALTJ_genes` is list and `[ALTJ_genes]` is nested list:

```
df1.drop(df1.columns.difference(ALTJ_genes), axis=1, inplace=True)
```

But simplier is select columns by list:

```
df1 = df1[ALTJ_genes]
```

EDIT:

I think problem is with defined columns with nested list, so get one level non standard MultiIndex:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4]])
#nested list
df1.columns = [['APEX1', 'ASF1A', 'CDKN2D', 'AAA']]
print (df1) 
  APEX1 ASF1A CDKN2D AAA
0     1     2      3   4

print (df1.columns)
MultiIndex([( 'APEX1',),
            ( 'ASF1A',),
            ('CDKN2D',),
            (   'AAA',)],
           )
```

If pass non nested list:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4]])
#not nested list
df1.columns = ['APEX1', 'ASF1A', 'CDKN2D', 'AAA']
print (df1) 
   APEX1  ASF1A  CDKN2D  AAA
0      1      2       3    4

print (df1.columns)
Index(['APEX1', 'ASF1A', 'CDKN2D', 'AAA'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thanks for this Jezrael! I had tried the selecting columns way but it did not work, maybe I am doing something incorrectly because when I select multiple columns from the list doing: df1[['APEX1', 'ASF1A', 'CDKN2D']] I get a result but when I pass my list it says "None of [Index([ ('APEX1',),  ('ASF1A',), ('CDKN2D',) ... name='Gene_Name')] are in the [columns]", trully lost! But thanks a lot, it got me thinking and gave me some new ideas to try!

Comment: @JourneyDS - How is created `DataFrame` ?

Comment: @JourneyDS - Answer was edited for explain possible problem.

Comment: The DataFrame comes from a CSV file separated by tabs I can post more information, maybe it helps to see the problem

Comment: @JourneyDS - What is `print (df.columns)` ? Ther eis MultiIndex?

Comment: This is what I get: Index(['A1BG', 'A1BG-AS1', 'A2M', 'A2M-AS1', 'A2ML1', 'A2MP1', 'A3GALT2',
       'A4GALT', 'AAAS', 'AACS',
       ...
       'ZYX', 'ZZEF1', 'ZZZ3', 'hsa-mir-1199', 'hsa-mir-125a', 'hsa-mir-335',
       'hsa-mir-6080', 'hsa-mir-6723', 'hsa-mir-7162', 'hsa-mir-8072'],
      dtype='object', name='Gene_Name', length=23987)

Comment: @JourneyDS - It is weird, `ALTJ_genes` is like `ALTJ_genes = ['APEX1', 'ASF1A', 'CDKN2D']` ?

Comment: It is actually longer, I simplified it into 3 to make it more readable. When I write type(ALTJ_genes) it says its a list. When I print it it looks like this: [['APEX1'],
 ['ASF1A'],
 ['CDKN2D'],
 ['CIB1'],
 ['DNA2'],
 ['FAAP24'],
 ['FANCM'],
 ['GEN1'],
 ['HRAS'],
 ['LIG1'],
 ['LIG3'],
 ['MEN1'],
 ['MRE11'],
 ['MSH3'],
 ['MSH6'],
 ['NUDT1'],
 ['MTOR'],
 ['NABP2'],
 ['NTHL1'],
 ['PALB2'],
 ['PARP1'],
 ['PARP3'],
 ['POLA1'],
 ['POLM'],
 ['POLQ'],
 ['PRPF19'],
 ['RAD51D'],
 ['RBBP8'],
 ['RRM2'],
 ['RUVBL2'],
 ['SOD1'],
 ['KAT5'],
 ['UNG'],
 ['WRN'],
 ['XRCC1']]

Comment: @JourneyDS - So there is problem, how is generated `ALTJ_genes` ?

Comment: That could be the problem, it was a CSV file with multiple rows. I used 1) ALTJ_genes = pd.read_csv('Data Sets/2.3. ALTEJgeneset.txt',sep='\n') and then 2) ALTJ_genes = ALTJ_genes.values.tolist()

Comment: Then change `ALTJ_genes = ALTJ_genes.values.tolist()` to `ALTJ_genes = ALTJ_genes.iloc[:, 0].values.tolist()` seelct first column to list

Comment: YES!!! It works! Thanks a lot for sticking up with me Jezrael! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Ok, I think I accepted it, it is the first time I port in stackoverflow, hopefully I did it correctly. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @JourneyDS - No problem, but green tick is missing for some reason...

Comment: Maybe I clicked twice, now should be green