# Cannot sort dataframe – the column label is not unique

Tags: python, pandas

I merge three dataframes with the first line and try to sort them with the second. This used to work fine, but now I get this error (our company may have updated the python version during this time):

```
ValueError: The column label 'Areanr' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.
```

The code looks like this

```
    pref_info4 = pref_info1.append(pref_info2).append(pref_info3)
    pref_info4 = pref_info4.sort_values(['Areanr','nr'])
```

The second line gives the error. When inspecting 'pref_info4' after the first line is done there is only one column with the label 'Areanr'. Is there some hidden labels that I need to remove? Otherwise it should be unique right? Each of the original dataframes has columns Areanr and nr, but this worked fine (and I cannot see any bad merging issue when inspecting pref_info4...)

Comment: `When inspecting 'pref_info4' after the first line is done there is only one column with the label 'Areanr'.` - So you test `print (pref_info4.columns[pref_info4.columns.duplicated(keep=False)])` ?

Comment: Also what return `print (pref_info4['Areanr'])` ?

Comment: The print returns:

ipdb> 0 1 2 3 4 etc    Areanr 1 1 1 2 2 2 etc

So yes there is several rows with the same areanr, this is why i sort on both 'areanr' and 'nr'. This used to work fine and is what I need. Is this no longer allowed?

Comment: hmmm, so no duplicated column names?

Comment: not when I inspect it in my IDE (spyder). Only one column named areanr and one called nr.

Comment: Also i try to verify why and when it became multi-index.   
But both "pref_info4.columns.nlevels" and "pref_info4.index.nlevels" gives the answer 1. Doesnt that mean that it's not multiindex but indeed a normal single index?

Comment: I think possible problem with set columns names, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60014438/python-pandas-dropping-multiple-columns-through-list/60014443#60014443)

Comment: I didn't understand how that could be related... But isnt it single-indexed if I get the result 1 from the lines above? Also i try this:
 ipdb> print (pref_info4.index)
Int64Index([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,
            ...
            104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113],
           dtype='int64', length=702) .
So it's not a multi-index right? So why do I even get this error to begin with?

Comment: What is `print (pref_info4.columns)` ? It is MultiIndex?

Comment: print (pref_info4.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['Areanr', 'Count', 'Failrate', 'Name', 'Omrade', 'Type', 'nan', 'nr']],
           labels=[[7, 3, 4, 5, 0, 2, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]])
So index is single but it's still "multi-indexed" since columns are multi? And why did the columns become multi-indexed and how can i remove that? Many parts of my code doesnt work anymore since it made itself multi-indexed all of a sudden :(

Comment: hmmm, test in each `DataFrame` like `print (pref_info1.columns)`,  `print (pref_info2.columns)`,  `print (pref_info3.columns)` - if MultiIndex in one of them it cause problem.

Comment: I found where the columns becomes multi-index! I process the column names. The dataframe starts out as single-index. I have the column names in a variable of type "list". Which i then apply to the dataframe like so: "pref_info1.columns = names". This makes the dataframe multi-index. Can I avoid this? Can I apply the names to the columns without making it multi-index (i never wanted multi-index and dont use it, it just showed up recently).

Comment: What is `names` ? How is created?

Comment: It starts as dataframe, then turns into list. This is just before it is applied to the columns. "names = df.iloc[start_row-2:start_row-1, start_col-1:end_col].astype(str)"      
    "names = names.values.tolist()."

Comment: hmmm, so problem is `names = df.iloc[start_row-2:start_row-1, start_col-1:end_col]` return more like 1 row?

Comment: that line results in a dataframe with one row and 61 columns. And i then convert that into a list with 61 posts.

Comment: I suggest use `names = df.iloc[start_row-2:start_row-1, start_col-1:end_col].iloc[0]`

Comment: That solved this problem! (no longer multi-indexed dataframe). Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to assign a running id to each columns so that they are unique and then sort them this running total